# How to show individual elements for the javascript loop function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show data from a JSON file unto a webpage using a boostrap slider. I have used the following javascript code:

```js
$(function functionName() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
          var restaurant = response.restaurant;
          var output = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < restaurant.length; i++) {
            output += "<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'>" + "<img class='d-block' width='100%' src=" + restaurant[i].image + "></div>" + "<div id='addd' class='col-sm-12'>" + restaurant[i].name + "</div>";
          }
          $(".carousel-item").html(output);
        });
```

```css
#txt {
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: relative;
  top: 500
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      <!-- 'active' element is needed for this plugin -->
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img class="d-block" width="100%" alt="img">
            </div>
            <div id="txt" class="col-sm-6">txt</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img class="d-block" width="100%" alt="img">
            </div>
            <div id="txt" class="col-sm-6">txt</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The data was successfully loaded on the page but it loaded all of the data once. The slide showed all of the information stacked on top the other while repeating the process every when a new slide is activated. I only want to show one object per slide. How can I parse the loop per object without stopping it entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function functionName() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
          var restaurant = response.restaurant;
          var output = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < restaurant.length; i++) {
            output += "<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'>" + "<img class='d-block' width='100%' src=" + restaurant[i].image + "></div>" + "<div id='addd' class='col-sm-12'>" + restaurant[i].name + "</div>";
          }
          $(".carousel-item").html(output);
        });
```

```css
#txt {
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: relative;
  top: 500
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      <!-- 'active' element is needed for this plugin -->
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img class="d-block" width="100%" alt="img">
            </div>
            <div id="txt" class="col-sm-6">txt</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <img class="d-block" width="100%" alt="img">
            </div>
            <div id="txt" class="col-sm-6">txt</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```